# How to use a different version of JRE on application run on Bluemix Liberty

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

By default JRE 8 is used with IBM Bluemix Liberty. Is it possible to use a different version of JRE to run the applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JBP_CONFIG_IBMJDK environment variable to specify an alternative version of the IBM JRE. For example, to use the IBM JRE 7.1 set the following environment variable:

$ cf set-env myapp JBP_CONFIG_IBMJDK "version: 1.7.+"